# IE table layout bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So I have a simple table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3">
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which should appear as:

```
---------------------------------
|       |                       |
---------------------------------
|       |       |       |       |
---------------------------------
|       |                       |
---------------------------------
```

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE it appears as a 2 column table. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

So I managed to replicate it:

```
<STYLE>
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
display:none;
}
label {
float:left;
height:0px;
width:0px;
}
.mytable {
width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:20px;
text-align:center;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
.mytable tr td:first-child {
border-right:1px solid #C5101A;
}
</STYLE>



<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%">
            hi
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="a" value="a" ><label for="m">First</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="b" value="b" ><label for="b">Second</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="c" value="c" ><label for="c">Third</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I also managed to fix it ... I just removed the `float:left;` from `label` ...
It also works if you remove `border-collapse` ... But I need that ...

Comment: This works in IE7, 8, & 9 for me.  I suggest looking somewhere else for the error...

Comment: Hmm ...  I'll have a look ... It's just weird that it works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE

Comment: When I try your code in IE I get the appearence that you expect. There is a missing `</td>` tag in the code, but that is not likely to cause that result. Could you link to a complete HTML page that shows this behaviour, or otherwise make it repeatable?

Comment: Yeah ... I'll try make it repeatable ... I'm figuring that it's a problem with my css, because It does display correctly when I remove the css page ...

Comment: could you post your CSS?

Comment: Just updated it ... Although I've found a work-around ... I'm still not sure why it happens in the first place